# Yii framework CActiveRecord

Tags: activerecord, constructor, yii, overriding, http-status-code-404

I want to make a universal CActiveRecord which could operate with any table. I add a class memeber `$table` and override `tableName()`

```
public function tableName()
{

    return $this->table;

}
```

In the final step I override the c-tor:

```
public function __construct($table , $scenario = 'insert')
{

    $this->table = $table;
    parent::__construct($scenario);

}
```

The c-tor of CActiveRecord calls a `tableName()` so we must define the table name before calling it.

I was pretty sure this would work fine, but I'm getting a `404 Not Found` when trying to create an instance of my class:

```
$foo = new Foo('table_foo');
```

Yii shows no errors, php neither, just a 404 error... The application works just perfect if I delete this line...

Comment: what's the exact 404 message?

Comment: `404 Not Found nginx/0.7.62`

Comment: so you don't get yii's 404 page, but you get nginx 404 page?

Comment: Yes, nginx 404 page. I'm very new to php and I've just found out, it doesn't(???) let to override c-tor? That's probably the problem...

Comment: quite probable, but that shouldn't result in a 404 error, afaik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have nginx 404 it's **not** yii problem. Check your rewrite rules. Perhaps, when you have application error, some redirect occur which result in 404?

Also I think you should not ovveride ctor like that. You added param to ctor in the beginning, so some yii internal instatiation might pass `insert` as first param, which would go as table name in your case!